# how to use server response and data in other functions in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, function, variables, swift3

am making a post request to a server and the server responds with some data,am storing the recived data in a variable named json now am trying to access this variable from other functions but i get an error : "use of unresolved identifier "json"
here is the code incase u need it

```
    @IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "url was here..lol") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "data to be posted"
    print(postString)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let response = response {
    print(response)
    }
       if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any]
                let token = json?["access_token"] as! String
                print (json)

        }
        }
        }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: Please give some more context, in its current form your question is very vague. It seems like you don't understand the scopes of variables, please read the Swift book by Apple as a starting point.

Comment: here is the thing the server responds with a token am storing this token in a variable now am trying to use that variable in other functions but for some reason i cant and i get an error : use of unresolved identifier "(variable name)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variables you want to share between functions on the class level so they can be accessed by each function in the class. `token` is an instance property of the class with this implementation, so each class instance has its own variable called token that can be accessed anywhere inside the class.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    var token = ""

    @IBAction func Login(_ sender: UIButton) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "url was here..lol") else {return}
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "data to be posted"
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
            if let data = data {
                guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])) as? [String: Any] else {return}
                guard let receivedToken = json["access_token"] as? String else {return}
                self.token = receivedToken
                otherFunction()
            }
        }
    task.resume()
    }

    func otherFunction(){
        print(token)
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way the compiler tells me to type "self.token = json?["access_token"] as! String" insted of "token = json?["access_token"] as! String" and i did so

Comment: You are doing a network request, which is asynchronous, so you have to call `otherFunction` from inside the completion handler of the network request, otherwise you would be trying to access the value before the network request returned. Check my updated answer.

Comment: it worked fine and just to let u know i changed "otherFunction()" to "self.otherFunction"